# Sabre Bargain Finder Max Soap Multiple Cabin Class Fare in 1 request

Tags: soap, soapui, sabre

Would like to know whether is it possible to request multiple cabin class fare in a single request.

i.e. I would like to request fare for Economy, Business and First cabin Class in a single request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending multiple FareParameters inside FlexibleFares:

OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ/TravelPreferences/TPA_Extensions/FlexibleFares/FareParameters

There is a Cabin element under FareParameters, with a Type attribute that allows you to select the cabin you want.